# vue-carousel can't remove outline color

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, carousel

I download vue carousel from libraby.
Here is my version
**"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",**

And when I click the pagination and class name add focus effect, and the focus effect will create with a outline color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ducRl.png)

I try to remove outline form /node_midules/vue-awesome/vue-carousel/scr/pagination.vue/

```
.VueCarousel-dot:focus {
  /* outline: 1px solid lightblue; */
  outline: none;
}
```

and also in the component's style.

```
 .VueCarousel-dot, .VueCarousel-dot:focus{
  outline: none !important;
}
```

But it still don't work, still have blue outline in focus effect.
How to fix them, Thanks!

Comment: have you tried [!important](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) css property

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it still didn't work.

Comment: can you create a minimal code example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: [codesanbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-shadow-qmxlr?file=/src/App.vue)
I can remove outline effect in codesandbox, but it can't work in local vscode project.

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting the wrong CSS selector

```
.VueCarousel-navigation-button:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

This removed the outline for me